# Target an opener after the popup has been refreshed

Tags: javascript, popup, popupwindow

I have a function that opens a popup

```
windowName = window.open("scriptName.php?&value="+value, "windowName");
windowName.focus();
```

That popup submits to itself using function that reloads the page with new variables passed in

Is there any way I can target the original opener after the script has refreshed?

`window.opener.functionName()` doesn't seem to work in this case

Comment: consider using `postMessage` to communicate between the two windows instead of using `opener`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I haven't used `postMessage` before - how would I use it in this case? `window.postMessage(functionName())'` that doesn't seem work (or am I missing something obvious?)